# XSLT replacement with namespaces?

Tags: java, xml, xslt

If I have an xml with namespaces and want to apply some values replacement, what do I have to change?
http://xslt.online-toolz.com/tools/xslt-transformation.php

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<accounts>
<account>
<name>Alex</name>
</account>
<account>
<name>Fiona</name>
</account>
</accounts>
```

This will change alle name values to "Johndoe":

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="account/name/text()">
   <xsl:text>JohnDoe</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But what if I have a namespace before very tag, like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<my:accounts>
<my:account>
<my:name>Alex</my:name>
</my:account>
<my:account>
<my:name>Fiona</my:name>
</my:account>
</my:accounts>
```

Comment: Please note that .. parent element will have namespace defined as an attribute `<my:accounts xmlns:my="my">` like this!! and this can't be avoided!!

Comment: ie, your Sample output XML I am talking about..

Comment: That's NOT an attribute, it's a namespace declaration. Common mistake, as it closely resembles one, but it's an important distinction.

Comment: yes that's namespace declaration but wanted to mention that it looks like an attribute .. :) just went a bit wrong in choosing words :)

Comment: Heh, it's ok.. sorry to be picky, but I've seen too many people try to match on `@xmlns:..`

Comment: @membersound, Flynn's answer had a small typo.. If you didn't get it working earlier, please try now.. It should work, as I have corrected it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways of doing this. Either include the 'my' namespace in the stylesheet tag like this:

`<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:my="(insertnamespacehere)">`

and do

`<xsl:template match="my:account/my:name/text()"`>

or do the rather clumsier:

`<xsl:template match="*[local-name()='account']/*[local-name()='name']/text()">`

I'd be inclined to discourage the latter approach though- namespaces exist to distinguish between elements that have the same local name (such as `employee:name` and `company:name` for example), by using `local-name()` you ignore that distinction. In other words, if your document happens to contains `foo:account/foo:name`, you'll accidentally replace that too.

Incidentally, your last sample XML isn't valid- the `my` namespace is not declared. Your root `my:accounts` would need to include this with `<my:accounts xlmns:my="(insertnamespacehere)">`

Comment: This can be generalized ! please refer my answer.. I mean to apply namespace to all elements in whole XML wouldn't need template match for each element separately ..

Comment: I think you're over-generalizing. He's already matching specific elements, all I'm doing is demonstrating how to modify that match to account for the namespace.

Comment: oh I thought you are applying namespace.. but where is your code to add namespace to elements? just having ` xmlns:my="my"` in declaration doesn't add namespace!

Comment: He didn't ask to add namespaces, he asked how to process elements that already have one.

Comment: oh! I misread it .. I am deleting my answer as its totally wrong .. ohkk.. local-name should do then!! as that will be generic :) +1..

Comment: works perfectly after adding the namespace also to my example xml.

Comment: Your xPath does not need to be so complex.  You can use a wildcard to match any namespace.  `*:account/*:name/text()` will match this and it is much more compact and readable.

Comment: Only in XPath 2.0 or later. The stylesheet he's using is XSLT 1.0.